# MySql Workbench csv data import error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I' trying to import a csv file in MySql WorkBench but get an error:

> Can't analyze file. Please, try to change encoding type. If that doesn't help, maybe the file is not: csv, or the file is empty.

I've tried to import the csv file create in Open Office Calac, Notepad++ or even just plain MS Notepad but no success. Of course I've set the encoding to UTF-8 in all of the programs.

Here is the the csv file content:

```
ę,1
ó,2
ą,3
```

Answer (score 2):

csv files are tricky.

You should have a header in your csv file and also mark strings with apostrophes

But for your csv you must select latin2 as encoding see image

[image: workbench]

You must choose the right encoding, because this determines how bits and bytes are interpreted.

so if you don't want ansi you have encode it properly

See here for *notepad++*

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Save your csv file as MS DOS instead of utf-8.

Comment: How does your answer differ from the previous answer? Please add an explanation, an example and possibly a reference to some material to support your answer. Thanks.